# Adding PCL reference causes "System.Object is not defined" error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a PCL  with this project.json:

```
 {
  "supports": {
    "net46.app": {},
    "uwp.10.0.app": {},
    "dnxcore50.app": {}
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore": "5.0.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.0",
    "System.ServiceModel.Primitives": "4.0.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dotnet": {
      "imports": "portable-net452+win81"
    }
  }
}
```

When I add a reference to my asp.net 5 web app, the resulting web app's project.json looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions" : "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "MyPcl": "1.0.0-*"
      }
    },
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "MyPcl": "1.0.0-*"
      }
    }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

Which from what I can tell should be correct, but it results in a couple of errors in the web app:

> Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported MyWebApp.DNX 4.5.1  C:\source\MyWebAppStartup.cs
>
> Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported   MyWebApp.DNX 4.5.1  C:\source\MyWebApp\Startup.cs

Ive found 100 ways to fix this, none have worked, and Im just not getting it.  Any help would be appreciated. (Im using VS2015)

EDIT: Restarting VS resolved those errors.  Now there is only this error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  MyWebApp    C:\source\MyWebApp\DNX  1